# Maximum value of the expression $E=\sin\theta+\cos\theta+\sin2\theta$.

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, optimization, maxima-minima

Find the maximum value of the expression $E=\sin\theta+\cos\theta+\sin2\theta$.

My approach is as follow ,let $E=\sin\theta+\cos\theta+\sin2\theta$, solving we  get

$E^2=1+\sin^22\theta+\sin2\theta+2\sin2\theta(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)$ not able to approach from here.

Comment: Maybe try to find the roots of the derivative?

Comment: Let $x:=\sin(\theta)+\cos(\theta)$.  Show that $E=x^2+x-1$ and the set of all possible values of $x$ is $[-\sqrt2,+\sqrt2]$.

Comment: Even simpler, note that $\sin(\theta)+\cos(\theta)\leq \sqrt{2}$ and $\sin(2\theta)\leq 1$.  (However, if you want to find the minimum value of $E$, my first comment is a better way.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @Batominovski's hint $$\left(\sin x+\cos x+\frac12\right)^2-\frac54=2\sin x\cos x+\sin x+\cos x$$ and the maximum value of $\sin x+\cos x$ is $\sqrt2$. Hence

$$\left(\sqrt2+\frac12\right)^2-\frac54=\sqrt2+1.$$

(The minimum is $-\dfrac54$ because the squared expression can vanish. There is also a local maximum with value $\left(-\sqrt2+\dfrac12\right)^2-\dfrac54=-\sqrt2+1$.)

Comment: The maximum value of $sinx+cosx$ is $\sqrt2$ and the max value of $sinx.cosx$ is $\frac{1}{2}$ and also occurs simultaneously. So, should this not be more straightforward to get $\sqrt 2+1$, unless we have to also find the minima?

Comment: It is a coincidence that this happens. In the domain $0 ≤ x ≤ \infty$, the minimum of $x$ is $0$, and the minimum of $\frac{1}{x}$ approaches $0$. Yet the minimum of $x + \frac{1}{x}$ is not $0 + 0$, but $2$.

Comment: @MathLover: the second insight of Batominovski is indeed an excellent one. In fact, there are two coincident stationary points, giving two stationary points of the sum, one being the global maximum.

Comment: @TobyMak - it is not a coincidence. It is due to the nature of the sine and cos curve. I am not able to relate to your analogy as those are happening for two different values of x.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, saw your edit. It is definitely interesting. Will study this further. Thanks.

Comment: @MathLover: indeed the relation is $(\sin x+\cos x)^2=1+\sin 2x$.

Answer (score 1):

$E = sin(\theta) + cos(\theta) + sin(2\theta) $ $=$  $ \sqrt{2} sin(\theta + \frac{\pi}{4}) + sin(2\theta)$

Replace $ \theta$ by $\theta -\frac{\pi}{4} $,

Then $E(\theta - \frac{\pi}{4}) = \sqrt{2} sin(\theta) - cos(2\theta) $ = $\sqrt{2}x - 1 + 2x^2 $ where $ x = sin(\theta)$

Now you can find the maximum of the quadratic function in the domain $[-1,1]$ which will be the maximum of the function $E$.

Answer (score 0):

$$E=\sin (\theta )+\cos (\theta )+\sin (2 \theta )$$
$$E'=\cos (\theta )-\sin (\theta )+2 \cos (2 \theta )$$ Use the tangent half-angle formula
$$\theta=2 \tan ^{-1}(x) \implies E'=\frac{x^4-2 x^3-12 x^2-2 x+3 } {(1+x^2)^2 }$$
$$x^4-2 x^3-12 x^2-2 x+3=\left(x^2-4 x-3\right) \left(x^2+2 x-1\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $$ \sin \theta = s, \cos \theta = c $$
We can use Lagrange Multiplier method to maximize/minimize

$$ c+s + 2 s c $$

subject to trig constraint

$$ c^2+s^2 =1 $$

$$\dfrac{1+2 s }{1+2c}=\dfrac{2c}{2s}$$

which simplifies to
$$ (s-c) (1+2s+2c)=0\;$$

$$s=c,\; s+c=-\dfrac12$$

These are two conditions one each for maximum and minimum evaluation:

First case maximum

$$ s=c; s^2+c^2=1\rightarrow s=c=1/\sqrt{2};\;$$

Maximum value
$$ 1/\sqrt{2}+ 1/\sqrt{2}+1 = 1+\sqrt{2}$$

Second case minimum
$$ s+c=-\frac12,\; s^2+c^2=1\;$$

$$ s= \dfrac{\sqrt7-1}{4};\;c= -\dfrac{\sqrt7+1}{4};$$

Minimum value
$$ s+c+ 2sc = =\dfrac{-5}{4}. $$

Both solutions verify on plot of $f( \theta)= s+c+sc\;$.